# JPA Exception while trying to persist bean to DATABASE

Tags: java, exception, javabeans, persist

New to JPA and encountered an issue.
Basically I am creating this bean:

```
PurchaseOrderControlBean purchaseOrderControl = new PurchaseOrderControlBean();
```

and using setters in order to fill it with data.

While trying to persist data to my DB I get this exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object is not a known entity type.
```

**My Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "IMS_PURCHASE_ORDER_CONTROL", schema = "IMS")
public class PurchaseOrderControlBean implements Serializable {
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5801211822984821162L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private BigDecimal id;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "INSURED_ID")
    private BigDecimal insuredId;
    
    @Column(name = "PROCESS_TYPE")
    private BigDecimal processType;
    
    @Column(name = "PROCESS_KEY")
    private String processKey;
    
    @Column(name = "SUPER_ClLAIM_NUM")
    private BigDecimal superClaimNum;
    
    @Column(name = "PURCHASE_ORDER_NUM")
    private BigDecimal processOrderNum;
    
    @Column(name = "PURCHASE_ORDER_SERVICE_TYPE")
    private BigDecimal PurchaseOrderServiceType;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CONTRACTOR_ID")
    private BigDecimal Contarctor_Id;
    
    @Column(name = "OPEN_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date openDate;
    
    @Column(name = "STATUS")
    private BigDecimal status;
    
    @Column(name = "EXECUTION_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date exccutionDate;
    
    @Column(name = "TOTAL_DURATION_DAYS")
    private BigDecimal totalDurationDays;
    
    @Column(name = "TOTAL_DELAY_DAYS")
    private BigDecimal totalDelayDays;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "UPDATE_USER_ID")
    private BigDecimal updateUserId;

    public BigDecimal getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(BigDecimal id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public BigDecimal getInsuredId() {
        return insuredId;
    }

    public void setInsuredId(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
        this.insuredId = bigDecimal;
    }

    public BigDecimal getProcessType() {
        return processType;
    }

    public void setProcessType(BigDecimal processType) {
        this.processType = processType;
    }

    public String getProcessKey() {
        return processKey;
    }

    public void setProcessKey(String processKey) {
        this.processKey = processKey;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSuperClaimNum() {
        return superClaimNum;
    }

    public void setSuperClaimNum(BigDecimal superClaimNum) {
        this.superClaimNum = superClaimNum;
    }

    public BigDecimal getProcessOrderNum() {
        return processOrderNum;
    }

    public void setProcessOrderNum(BigDecimal processOrderNum) {
        this.processOrderNum = processOrderNum;
    }

    public BigDecimal getPurchaseOrderServiceType() {
        return PurchaseOrderServiceType;
    }

    public void setPurchaseOrderServiceType(BigDecimal purchaseOrderServiceType) {
        PurchaseOrderServiceType = purchaseOrderServiceType;
    }

    public BigDecimal getContarctor_Id() {
        return Contarctor_Id;
    }

    public void setContarctor_Id(BigDecimal contarctor_Id) {
        Contarctor_Id = contarctor_Id;
    }

    public Date getOpenDate() {
        return openDate;
    }

    public void setOpenDate(Date openDate) {
        this.openDate = openDate;
    }

    public BigDecimal getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(BigDecimal status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public Date getExccutionDate() {
        return exccutionDate;
    }

    public void setExccutionDate(Date exccutionDate) {
        this.exccutionDate = exccutionDate;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTotalDurationDays() {
        return totalDurationDays;
    }

    public void setTotalDurationDays(BigDecimal totalDurationDays) {
        this.totalDurationDays = totalDurationDays;
    }

    public BigDecimal getTotalDelayDays() {
        return totalDelayDays;
    }

    public void setTotalDelayDays(BigDecimal totalDelayDays) {
        this.totalDelayDays = totalDelayDays;
    }

    public BigDecimal getUpdateUserId() {
        return updateUserId;
    }

    public void setUpdateUserId(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
        this.updateUserId = bigDecimal;
    }
```

**Persist Method:**

```
public Object save(Object obj) throws TecnicalException {
        EntityManager entityManager = null;
        EntityTransaction updateTransaction = null;
        Object object = null;
        boolean success = false;
        try {
            entityManager = PersistenceUtil.getEntityManager(dbName);
            updateTransaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
            updateTransaction.begin();
            object = entityManager.merge(obj);
            success = true;
        } catch (PersistenceException e) {
            logger.error("Exception while trying to update object " + obj, e);
            ErrorLogUtil.writeErrorLog(Application.PERSISTANCE, "mng", null, "BaseDAO-Exception while trying to update object " + obj, "");
            throw new TecnicalException(e);
        } finally {
            if (success) {
                try {
                    updateTransaction.commit();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Failed commit" + e);
                    throw new TecnicalException(e);

                }
            } else {
                if (updateTransaction != null && updateTransaction.isActive()) {
                    updateTransaction.rollback();
                }
            }
            if (entityManager != null) {
                entityManager.close();
                entityManager = null;
            }
        }
        return object;
    }
```

When debugging the exception occurs on

```
object = entityManager.merge(obj);
```

I cannot seem to understand what I am missing here.
I could add any more information if needed.

I saw similar issues on other threads, however, it did not help me.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps JPA is not configured to detect entities; if so you need to declare the class in persistence.xml.

Comment: It does, since there are other entities created by other people on this project.